# String with space slicing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a txt document which has a lot of lines like this:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
```

I need to slice the 'day' part out. In this example, it would be Sat, position index = 2.

I have the following code, which works:

```
for line in thetxtfile:
    if line.startswith('From '): # watch there is a space after the string 'From'
    line = line.split()
    day = line[2]  # slice the 'day' part out, position index = 2
    dict[day] = dict.get(day,0) + 1
```

But I noticed that if I don't add a space after 'From', the above code would return an indexerror: list index out of range.

That is, if I rewrite the if statement like the following, the error would occur:

```
if line.startswith('From') # watch there's no space after the string 'From'
```

If I don't add a space after 'From', the position index 0 can return 'From' correctly; position index 1 can return the email address correctly. But starting from position index 2, it's out of range.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: `print(line)` in your for loop and check out how is it

Comment: There is a line that starts with `From:` in your headers that passes the second check but does not pass the first check. It has a different structure and does not have a day in the expected position. P.S. **Do not call your variables `dict`!**

Comment: @DYZ you are right... Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question with a few examples of lines that cause the problem?